# access template variable method in c++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a template say A:

```
template <class T>
class A {
 int key;
 T value;
}
```

and a class B:

```
class B {
public:
string name;
double num;
 someMethod();
};
```

I created a template initialization as `A<B> something;`, my question is, how do I access the variables and method in `B` using `something`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not `public`...

Comment: if I change it to public

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, as `value` is not `public`.

If you make it `public`, you can access it as `something.value.fieldname` and `something.value.methodname()`.

Alternatively, if you want to hide the implementation, you can add a public method to `A` that will be able to access them and then call that method.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I access the variables and method in `B` using `something`

Provide access to `value` in `A`, by either making `value` a `public` member variable or by providing an accessor function.

**Make `value` a `public` member**

```
template <class T>
class A {
 public:
   int key;
   T value;
}
```

and then use it as:

```
something.value.someMethod();
```

**Provide access to `value` using a  `public` member function**

```
template <class T>
class A {
   int key;
   T value;
 public:
   T& getValue() { return value; }
   T const& getValue() const { return value; }
}
```

and then use it as:

```
something.getValue().someMethod();
```

Comment: Your `getValue` method is pointless. You could make your example useful by e.g. providing access to one member of `B` but not the whole `B` field.

Comment: I'm wondering the difference between the two methods `T& getValue() { return value; }` and `T const& getValue() const { return value; }` and also the difference with `T getValue() { return value; }`, if I use `T getValue() { return value; }`, it's just call by value and the value won't change in A, is that the difference?

Comment: @anatolyg, that is not possible in `A` since there is no way of knowing what type will be used to instantiate it.

Comment: @al3xtouch, This is standard stuff when dealing with `const` objects of a type. Please have a look at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html.